# Python Flask API cannot handle multiple requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, concurrency, flask-restful

I have created a Python Flask API which basically accepts `POST` requests containing **PDF documents**, performs **OCR** on them and then runs a couple **Deep Learning** models on the text extracted.

I am using **Multi threading** in the **OCR engine** to extract the text from the pages **concurrently**. So the OCR will **utilise all the threads available** in the server in order to extract the text.

For a PDF document with **87 pages** it takes about **70 seconds** for the API to give a response.

If I send a **single request** through Postman, everything works great and I get a response. The issue arises when **multiple requests** are sent. Then I get no response and the API execution keeps on utilising the system resources. Even if I wait for 30 mins I still get no response. On analysing the results of `htop` I find that all the threads are being used at 100% but I do not get a response. I am running the API as follows with the `threaded=True` argument:

```
app.run(debug=False, port = 6996, host = '0.0.0.0', threaded = True)
```

I don't know what the issue is. Any help/guidance will be much appreciated. Any links to articles or videos will help me too. Thanks in advance!

**PS:** Below is the flow of the API.

1. Convert PDF to image format.
2. Extract text from all the images using OCR engine. (Multi threading. Here all the available threads will be utilised!).
3. Clean the text extracted.
4. Run a couple Deep Learning models on the cleaned text and prepare the response.

Comment: which flask version you are using ? and can you share your code for which you are processing this data

Comment: Latest Flask version. Unfortunately cannot share the code as it is confidential. But I have added the flow of the API in the question.

Comment: have you used async and await ? if possible you can try [quart](https://palletsprojects.com/p/quart/) for async handling

Comment: @sahasrara62 Please correct me if I'm wrong but `Multi Threading`, `Multi Processing` and `asyncio` are used at code level for concurrency right? Are you sure that using `asyncio` which basically introduces concurrency at code level will make the API handle multiple requests?

Comment: this will add the current process in event loop and from there can take another request and wont block io